# Replace %20 string in URL with Underscore using SQL Server Database Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, rollback

I have a column in my SQl Server DB table that has URL's with a %20 in the string.
I'm trying to replace the %20 with an underscore '_'.
Every URL is different up to a certain point. It's about 1500 records that need to be updated. I want to do a bulk update on all records Using this Update.

However the query is successful, Nothing changes in the DB. Perhaps because of the Rollback statement?

Here is my SQL code:

```
Begin Try


    declare @newStringCount as int;
    declare @oldString as nvarchar(MAX);
    declare @newString as nvarchar(MAX);
    declare @stringToReplace as nvarchar(MAX);  
    set @stringToReplace = (SELECT resourceurl FROM [dbo].[ContentResourceBak2] where resourceurl like '%%20%');
    Set @oldString = '%20';
    Set @newString = '_';


  Update [dbo].[ContentResourceBak2] 
  Set resourceurl = REPLACE(@stringToReplace, @oldString, @newString)  


  Commit
  End Try
  Begin Catch

  set @newStringCount = (SELECT count (resourceurl) FROM [dbo].[ContentResourceBak2] where resourceurl like  '%%20%');
  if @newStringCount > 0
  RollBack

  END Catch
```

All 1500 records still contain the %20 and NO underscores.
**Update: The reason I am replacing %20 with underscore is because the URL maps to files in blob storage that have _ between each word.

Comment: Why underscore and not space? `%20` is the placeholder for a space. Underscore would be `%5F`.

Comment: Probably they changed the way their URLs work on the website and now they need to update the database to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @stringToReplace = (SELECT resourceurl FROM [dbo].[ContentResourceBak2] where resourceurl like '%[%]20%');
```

But be careful of this:

```
Update [dbo].[ContentResourceBak2] 
Set resourceurl = REPLACE(@stringToReplace, @oldString, @newString)
```

*There's no WHERE condition on that UPDATE statement.*  It will change **every** row in the table.
**If you tested this in production, you probably just ruined your data.** Every record will now have *same* value in the `resourceurl` column, and the only way to fix it will be restoring from backup.

You probably want this:

```
UPDATE[dbo].[ContentResourceBak2] 
SET resourceurl = REPLACE(resourceurl, @oldString, @newString)  
WHERE resourceurl like '%[%]20%';
```

Finally, `%20` is the code for a space character. If you want to be true to your data, a space is probably better here. If the URL wanted an underscore, it would have used `%5F`. Sticking with space will mean client code can URL-encode the string again and get a correct result. Which makes me wonder if you might not be better keeping the raw data, and letting client code URL decode as needed. `%20` isn't the only hex character you could end up with.

Comment: In the end I doubt that there is a good reason to do the replacement at all. I have a strong hunch that the OP is probably trying to parse the URL string with something other than an URL parser, which fell apart at the `%20`. It will fall apart again at the next encoded character.